# Spring Boot Validation not working with Generics

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I try to validate buy Spring Boot Validation but I can not valid Generics Type.
I   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation' in build.gradle
I have a object:

```
public class BaseAPIRequestDTO<T, U> {
@NotNull
private T content;
@NotNull
private U info;
@NotEmpty
private String signature;}
```

and Generic Object:

```
public class ContentRequestDTO {
@NotNull
@NotEmpty(message = "Thiếu transactionId")
private String transactionId;
private DataRequestDTO data;}
```

.....
and controller:

```
   public ResponseEntity<BaseAPIResponseDTO<ContentResponseDTO, InfoResponseDTO>> connnnnn(@RequestBody @Valid BaseAPIRequestDTO< @Valid ContentRequestDTO, @Valid  InfoRequestDTO> request, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
```

But I when I clear transactionId on of ContentResponseDTO in request, bindingResult has 0 error
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhzg8.png)

What do I need to do now? Thank so much.

Comment: Isn't your `@Valid` annotation should be before the `@RequestBody` annotation?

Comment: @user404 The order of annotations is unimportant.

Comment: The order of annotation is unimportant. "signature" param of BaseAPIRequestDTO object is still validate

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add @Valid in BaseAPIRequestDTO attributes?

Example:

```
public class BaseAPIRequestDTO<T, U> {
   @Valid
   @NotNull
   private T content;
   @Valid
   @NotNull
   private U info;
   @NotEmpty
   private String signature;
}
```

This should work.